# Retrieve value of class variable

Tags: tikz-pgf, exam

I'm attempting to use exams' documentclass builtin variable in a formula, regrettably I get an error. ( ! Missing number, treated as zero. )

Is there a way to retrieve this variable so it can be used in a formula?

*MWE*:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,answers]{exam}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question[2] A Question
\question[2] A Question
\end{questions}

\pgfmathparse{2* \numpoints }\pgfmathresult  \

%Should eval to: 8

\end{document}
```

Comment: Both `\pgfmathparse{2*\numpoints}\pgfmathresult ` and  `\pgfmathparse{2*\pointsonpage{1}}\pgfmathresult` output 8.0.

Comment: @SimonDispa: Is that the case if there is not already an existing `.aux` file (ie on the first run)?

Comment: The first command will fail on the first run, the second works. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: @SimonDispa: Have you actually tried it? The above MWE won't compile for me in the first run, so can't get to the second run without additional code.

Comment: We must assume exams will have multiple pages, having a variable where the points get input would be more feasible than adding up multiple \pointsonpage{#}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `numpoints` is stored in the `.aux` file as `\exam@numpoints`. So you can define a macro to get this value:

```
\makeatletter
    \providecommand{\exam@numpoints}{0}%
    \newcommand{\GetNumPoints}{\exam@numpoints}%
\makeatother
```

and use `\GetNumPoints` when you need it.  This requires more than one run. The output is

[image]

on the initial run, but on subsequent runs it is:

[image]

Similarily, if you change the questions, this will require two runs to get the correct value.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[addpoints,answers]{exam}

\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
    \providecommand{\exam@numpoints}{0}%
    \newcommand{\GetNumPoints}{\exam@numpoints}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
    \question[2] A Question
    \question[2] A Question
\end{questions}

\pgfmathparse{2* \GetNumPoints }\pgfmathresult

%Should eval to: 8

\end{document}
```

Comment: Solved it again Peter, Thank you for your invaluable support!